# Copy text from span to other span

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to copy contents of one span to another span on anchor click even.

It works fine if i remove the wrapper title div's example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/27/)

when i wrap them inside div it doesnt work anymore i tried different thing so far i am not able to find right property or function to use.

This one needs fix [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/30/)

```
<div style="float:left; width=800px;" id="video_container">
    <iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vOnCRWUsSGA?wmode=transparent&rel=0&theme=light&color=white&autoplay=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1"></iframe>
</div>
<span class="active-video-title">Title</span>

<span class="active-video-date">Date</span>

<div class="row">
    <br> <a href="oDAw7vW7H0c" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">Thumnnail 1</span>
       <div class="title-wrapper">
            <span class="title">Title of the Video 1</span>
             <span class="date">Date  1</span>
        </div>
        </a>

    <br> <a href="5F-Wge37_ys" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">Thumnnail 2</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper">
            <span class="title">Title of the Video 2</span>
             <span class="date">Date  2</span>
            </div>
        </a>

</div>
<div class="row2">
    <br> <a href="oDAw7vW7H0c" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">featured Thumnnail 1</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper-control">
            <span class="featured-title">featured Title of the Video 1</span>
             <span class="featured-date">featured Date  1</span>
        </div>
        </a>

    <br> <a href="5F-Wge37_ys" class="play-youtube">
            <span class="youtube-thumbnail">featured Thumnnail 2</span>
        <div class="title-wrapper-control">
            <span class="featured-title">featured Title of the Video 2</span>
             <span class="featured-date">featured Date  2</span>
        </div>
        </a>

</div>
```

Comment: @Gatkeeper, It is all on fiddle i have linked it..

Comment: From jQuery docs: "The `.children()` method differs from `.find()` in that `.children()` only travels a single level down the DOM tree while `.find()` can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements as well."

Comment: When you change DOM, you have to adapt when needed transversing methods too. You just have to understand which methods you are using...

Comment: @pawel, Good point. let me see if i can fix it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) will get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

Use [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method which will get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element.:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.play-youtube').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var URL = $(this).attr('href');
        var htm = '<iframe width="438" height="250" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' + URL + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" ></iframe>';


        $(".active-video-title").html($(this).find(".title").html());
         $(".active-video-date").html($(this).find(".date").html());
        $(".active-video-title").html($(this).find(".featured-title").html());
        $(".active-video-date").html($(this).find(".featured-date").html());
        return false;
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/KSMZ9/31/)**</kbd>